# How to search for errors across different CI runs?

Tags: error-reporting, circleci, intermittent

I can see that an individual job failed

[image]

and I can go into the details and see the failure

[image]

but is there any way I can search across all the different runs and branches for this repository and see which ones have a certain failure?

Primary I'm talking about intermittent failures and looking for the ability to search thousands of runs and failures to find out which ones included a certain error.

It's probably evem more complicated by the fact that some runs will have multiple failures.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with their API is one way to go about it.

[This project](https://github.com/rockymadden/circleci-cli) is a CLI tool to interact with the circle. There is also [this Ruby gem](https://github.com/mtchavez/circleci), which looks more recently updated.

Pesudo steps to get the information you want:

- Get all builds
- Iterate all builds
- Search build for matching errors
- Record the branch/build that it was encountered